# Sorting dates by year then month in php / sql

Tags: php, sql, sorting, date, myisam

My MySQL database is for my record shop.

I have a table called records with 700 records in it.

My fields are artist, title, release_date, etc.

The release_date is varchar and entered and stored as *mm/yyyy*.

I.e., 01/2003 = Jan 2003

I.e., zz/1997 = during 1997. Some records don’t have a month.

I want to be able to sort, display the records in order of year, and then month in my results. I.e., so I can show the visitor a list of the top 10 most recent records. If a record starts with zz, then it would be last in order of the list for that year.

An example sort results would be thus:

11/2001

06/2001

zz/2001

09/2000

01/2000

zz/2000

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Create another column and store the date correctly `YY/mm/dd`  with `/dd` optional or `00` or some default.

Comment: thanks abracadaver but I dont want to have to go through 700 entries and change them to unix date format ... It would take ages !

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
order by right(release_date, 4) desc,
         left(release_date, 2) + 0 desc;
```

A note on the second key.  This converts the month to a number.  The value `zz` will be converted to 0 because there are no leading digits.